# Bash Compound/Nested Conditional Operator issue

Tags: bash, operators

I have my Bash code like this:

```
copiedFlag=false
..
if [...]
cp originalFile newFile && copiedFlag=true
fi
..
if[....]
copiedFlag || ( cp originalFile newFile && copiedFlag=true )
fi
..

if [ copiedFlag == true ]; then
cp newFile originalFile
fi
..
```

The compound condition `copiedFlag || ( cp originalFile newFile && copiedFlag=true )` somehow doesn't work.

But if I do this, it works:
`copiedFlag || cp originalFile newFile && copiedFlag=true`

This is an important step in my logic, hence I want to ensure that my assignment is absolutely correct by enclosing it in braces. Why does this not work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you missed a `$`: `$copiedFlag || ( cp originalFile newFile && copiedFlag=true )`

Comment: You must dereference/expand `copiedFlag` everywhere outside assignments to it, thus also in `if [ $copiedFlag == true ]; then ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The compound condition `copiedFlag || ( cp originalFile newFile && copiedFlag=true )` somehow doesn't work.

It doesn't work because you are forking a new subshell and changes made to `copiedFlag` are not visible in current shell.

You don't really need to spawn a subshell here, just use brace expression `{ ...; }` as:

```
"$copiedFlag" || { cp originalFile newFile && copiedFlag=true; }
```

Comment: The test must start with a `$`: `$copiedFlag || { cp originalFile newFile && copiedFlag=true; }`

Comment: Great Anubhava. I had put the $ alright, but I think the curly brace is the winner. ! will try it out and update shortly.